# How do I get Apache to run? Port 443 in use by "unable to open process"

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I've been trying to start apache (which I installed via xampp) but I keep getting this error message

```
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   Problem detected!
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   Port 443 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 25792!
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
12:45:52 PM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

My default port is port 80 so I don't understand why I am getting the error. I can't see any services or applications using port 443 and when I try to reconfigure to port to 8080 it still doesn't work. Im stuck and I don't know what else to try.